# Error: ; expected (Compile error in Java)

Tags: java

When `isLetter()` method is deleted everything is working fine but when I add it it gives an error. I removed private as it is in the main method. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
class WordCounter{

public static void main(String args[]){
    File file_in_obj = new File("E:/Problems","notes.txt");
    File file_out_obj = new File("E:/Problems","notes_sorted.txt");

    boolean isLetter(char let){
        return ( let>= 'a'&& let <= 'z') || ( let >= 'A' && let <='Z');
    }

    try(BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_in_obj));
    BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_out_obj));){

    String array[]=new String[500];
    char ch[]=new char[25];
    int rd,k=0;
    String line=null;

        /*do{
            rd=fin.read();
            if(Character.isWhitespace((char)rd))
                fout.write(" ");
            else if(Character.isLetter((char)rd)){

                    fout.write((char)rd);
                }
        }while(rd!=-1); */

        while((line=fin.readLine())!=null){
            //  System.out.println(j++);
            String[] tokens = line.split ("\\s+"); 
            for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                    array[k]=tokens[i];
                    fout.write(array[k]+" ");
                    k++;
                    //System.out.println(tokens.length);
            }

        }
        for(int p=0;p<k;p++){
            for(int i=0;i<array[p].length();i++){
                if(Character.isLetter(array[p].charAt(i)))
                    System.out.print(array[p].charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println(p);
        }

    /*for(int j=tokens.length;j>1;j--)
    for(int i=0;i<j-1;i++){
        if(tokens[i].compareTo(tokens[i+1])>0){
                String temp=tokens[i+1];
                tokens[i+1]=tokens[i];
                tokens[i]=temp;
        }
    }*/

    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("I/O Exception occured");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Asked and answered many times before: don't put a method inside of another method. End. Full stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a method inside another method.  Try this:

```
boolean isLetter(char let){
        return ( let>= 'a'&& let <= 'z') || ( let >= 'A' && let <='Z');
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    File file_in_obj = new File("E:/Problems","notes.txt");
    File file_out_obj = new File("E:/Problems","notes_sorted.txt");
...
}
```